# Is there a command to find and then print a line from a document?

Tags: command-line, printing, log

I'm trying to create a scheduling program. Basically, the way I want it to work is that you can choose an option to add or remove an item from your schedule, or view your schedule for today. When you choose to add an item, you give it the information, and it saves it to a text file. I want to make it so that when you view your schedule, it prints any lines that have today's date corresponding to them. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: There are lots of commands that can selectively prints lines from a text file, based either on line number (ex. `sed -n '3,5p' somefile`) or on a regular expression or fixed string match (ex. `grep -F foo somefile`). It's hard to give you a specific recommendation based on the information in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let <path/filename> equal the full path to your text file.
Let {searchyword} equal the part or entire word you are searching for.
`sudo cat <path/filename> | grep -i {searchword}`
**Dont' forget the / at the start of your path**

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. This is incredibly useful.